# How to show an entity from OrionContextBroker in the MapViewer widget

Tags: fiware-orion, fiware-wirecloud

I am trying to show an entity stored in my OrionContextBroker instance in the Wirecloud MapViewer widget. I create the context using this JSON POST REST request to *miOrionInstance:1026/v1/updateContext* like this:

```
{
    "contextElements": [
        {
            "type": "Room",
            "isPattern": "false",
            "id": "Room1",
            "attributes": [
            {
                "name": "position",
                "type": "string",
                "value": "43.47258, -3.8026643"
            }
            ]
        }
    ],
    "updateAction": "APPEND"
}
```

I am able to recover this information through the *NGSIUpdater Widget* with no problem, but I am unable to show this entity in the MapViewer widget. I have tried to wire the *NGSISource Operator* to the *NGSIEntityToPol Operator* and finally to the *MapViewer Widget* (in Insert/Update centered Pol).
The configuration of the *NGSISource operator* is:

```
NGSI server URL: http://miOrionInstanceIP:1026
NGSI proxy URL: http://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org
NGSI entity types: Room
Id Pattern:
Monitored NGSI Attribures: position
```

And the configuration of the *NGSIEntityToPol Operator* is the following:

```
Coordinates attribute: position
```

But nothing appears in the map.

Thanks,

Comment: try to change "NGSI entity types" to "Room"

Comment: for clarifying, the "NGSI entity types" setting should point to a entity type nor to an entity Id ;-).

Comment: @ÁlvaroArranz thnxs for the quick help but still not working :'(   I've changed the "NGSI entity types" to Room, I added http:// to the "NGSI server URL" option and I changed the proxy to http://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org

Comment: i've updated the question according to the new configuration

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "NGSI entity types" value is incorrect, it should contain the entity type of the entities you are interested in (e.g. Room). The rest of your configuration seems correct, so if changing this setting doesn't solve your problems, you may be facing the same problems described at this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27129318/how-to-show-an-entity-from-in-the-wirecloud-mapviewer-widget).

Comment: Still not working :'( I've changed the "NGSI entity types" to Room, I added http:// to the "NGSI server URL" option and I changed the proxy to http://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org. I've updated the question according to the new configuration.

Comment: I'm guessing you are working at the FIWARE Lab Mashup portal, so, have you seen a shield icon in the address bar of your web browser? You need to allow mixed content for connecting to http://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org :(.<br/>

The only way to fix that is to configure your context broker instance using Rush and using `https://ngsiproxy.lab.fi-ware.org` as NGSI proxy.